# How to Catch java.io.EOFException in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm creating a new rest service and just noticed if don't pass any data in the post I receive a `java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input`. Turns out the Jackson mapper can't handle an empty body.

Control never comes to my code. Where is the right place to hook into the lifecycle to catch the exception?

Comment: Why not just send something minor?

Comment: Did you try @ExceptionHandler?